# How to create a Sparkline chart for for a particular name with values depending on the fields of other cells?

Tags: looker-studio, sparklines

I need help creating a sparkline chart for an example data as below:

| name | timestamps | test | action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| try 1 | 2022-11-16 22:39:35.653819+00:00 | TRUE | TRUE |
| try 2 | 2022-11-16 22:39:33.171203+00:00 | TRUE | TRUE |
| try 1 | 2022-11-16 22:39:30.699472+00:00 | FALSE | TRUE |
| try 4 | 2022-11-16 22:39:27.711734+00:00 | TRUE | FALSE |

Let's say I am only trying to create a sparkline chart for try 1 against the timestamps.

What I want the chart to show is:

If test and action is TRUE and TRUE then for that timestamp Try 1 value is 2
If test and action is TRUE and FALSE then for that timestamp Try 1 value is 1
If test and action is FALSE and FALSE then for that timestamp Try 1 value is 0

I don't want to 'code' this into the google sheet as the data uploaded will be refreshed automatically and all my code will be gone when the data is refreshed.

Is there anyway I can code this into the sparkline chart itself on google data studio?

I tried creating a field in the metric section of the sparkline chart but it gives a system error.

Comment: Sorry for putting the table in a code. Stack was not letting me upload without putting the table in a code format

Comment: are you attempting for sparkline chart/graph or formula/function?

Comment: @player0 I am trying to create a sparkline chart . But I was wondering if there was some way I can code the formula into the chart or do I have to do it on a different sheet on google sheet and then make the chart based on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hopefully this should get you started.

fix the timestamp to be studio-compatible

```
PARSE_DATETIME("%F %H:%M:%E*S",LEFT_TEXT(timestamps,26))
```

get the value score from test and action

```
CASE WHEN action='TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END+CASE WHEN test='TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

you can use both these calculated fields as dimension and metric for spark chart.

[image]

lastly you can apply a filter to chart to see just the 'try 1' score.
[image]